# WP 8 WCF Error when run on device

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have an WP 8 app that consumes a WCF service hosted in my IIS 8. If I run the app from VS2013 and choose the device or emulator, the apps works fine. If I deploy the app and run the app direct from the device, the apps show the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Stack. tRACE: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(MessageReply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version)...

Here is my app.config of my WCF service:

```xml
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Metadata" name="WCFDataLibrary.EnvioDados">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
      listenUriMode="Explicit">
      <identity>
        <dns value="http://192.168.1.5" />
        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint 
      address="http://192.168.1.5/wcfdatasite/EnvioDados.svc" 
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="WCFDataLibrary.IEnvioDados"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/WCFDataService" />-->
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.5/WCFDataService/EnvioDados" />
    </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Like I said, everything works well when I run the app on the device from my VS2013, but it's not working when I deploy the app to the same device and run the app just using the device's wireless.

Comment: That doesn't look like an external IP address ...

Comment: @McGarnagle Although you are right and OP will have problems when releasing the app, OP didn't say, if he tested the app in the local network, what would be fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is OP ?

Comment: This app is for use just in internal intranet and not the internet...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the serviceMetadata configuration.

The original key was:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://192.168.1.5/WCFDataService/meta"/>
```

and the correct value needs to be:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://192.168.1.5/WCFDataService/meta?wsdl" />
```

Now it's working perfectly!